# Solr update performance

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, search-engine, solr4

For example, In one of our application we have 2 cores to store the buyer details.

Core 1 : Buyer Which is responsible for storing the buyer meta data(like name, about etc)
Core 2: BuyerRequest Which is responsible for storing the buyer requests posted by a buyer along with the buyer meta data.(We are storing buyer meta data, since we have an requirement to display these in search results).

Suppose one of the buyer has posted 50 buyer requests. If this buyer updates his meta data, We need to update the same thing in buyer core and buyer request core.

How can we handle such situations without much of performance bottlenecks?

Comment: How often do you actually have updates of that kind of metadata? Those 50 updated documents will take a fraction of a second - usually not an issue in any real world load.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the update. There are few of the fields in metadata which can be updated very often.  If the core size is in terms of millions and updating the chunk of the core would trigger reindex of the core. Would this create a spike in CPU usage and query performance?